# Prove that $\gamma$ is a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $Q = \{A \subset \mathbb{R}: A \text{ countable or } A^c \text{ countable} \}$ and $\gamma: Q \to \{0,1\}$, where $\gamma(A) = 0$ if $A$ is countable, $\gamma(A) = 1$ otherwise.

I struggle with showing one of the properties that this is a measure,

$$
\gamma(\cup_{i=1}^{n} A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \gamma (A_i)
$$

This I want I came up with:

Let $A_i \in Q$ be pairwise disjoint, $i\in \mathbb{N}$ and order them s.t for $i = 1,\dots,k \ k\leq n$ are not countable and for $i=k,\dots,n$ countable. Then

$$
\gamma (\cup_{i=1}^{n} A_i) = \gamma (\cup_{i=1}^{k} A_k) \cup \gamma ( \cup_{i=k}^{n} A_i)
$$

I know that a countable union of countable sets is countable, hence $\gamma ( \cup_{i=k}^{n} A_i) = 0$. But this is all I got.

Answer (score 3):

If the $A_k$ are pairwise disjoint, then **at most** one of them can be the complement of a countable set.

To see this, suppose $A_1$ is the complement of a countable set, then we must have $A_k \subset A_1^c$ for all $k>1$, and since $A_1^c$ is countable, so is $A_k$.

In particular, if $A_k$ are pairwise disjoint, then there are only two cases to consider: (i) All are countable. (ii) Exactly one is the complement of a countable set and the rest are countable.

The desired result follows from these two cases.

Comment: Why can it be at most one? Because otherwise the two (or more) who are complement will not be disjoint?

Comment: @Olba12: I have elaborated the answer a little.